# Ruby array subtraction error

Tags: ruby

I have been looking around for this and I think the answer is easy but I can not figure it out.

I have two files 1.txt and 2.txt that contain one IP address per line. I need to remove all ips listed in 2.txt from 1.txt

1.txt:

```
1.2.3.4
5.6.7.8
9.10.11.12
13.14.15.16
```

2.txt:

```
5.6.7.8
9.10.11.12
```

what I have now:

```
my_array = IO.readlines('1.txt')
my_array2 = IO.readlines('2.txt')
my_array3 = my_array - my_array2
puts my_array3
```

array3 output:

```
1.2.3.4
9.10.11.12
13.14.15.16
```

the amount of IPs in 2.txt changes all the time so looking for a way to always remove all of the contents of 2.txt from 1.txt

Comment: Try using something like `IO.readlines('1.txt').map(&:chomp).map(&:strip)` for both arrays - to clean each line from `"\n"`'s, and strip all white space. Does the problem persist?

Comment: Does the `9.10.11.12` in `2.txt` have a newline after it? The one in `1.txt` does, obviously.

Comment: Thanks Jorg that was it doh!

Answer (score 0):

The newline character was causing the problem.  It works now after removing.